# Как передать несколько параметров из представления в контролер в ASP. NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Например, в контролере есть функция со входными параметрами Function (string str, int number). Какие есть пути реализации передачи параметров из представления в такой метод?

Answer (score 5):

У вас заголовок вопроса противоречит самому вопросу, вы уж определитесь куда вы хотите передать: `Controller->View` или `View->Controller`

**View->Controller**

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", FormMethod.Post)
{
    <input type="text" name="str" value="String"/>
    <input type="text" name="number" value="1002"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
}
```

Comment: поправил заголовок вопроса

Comment: а как быть в том случае, если нужно передать несколько сложных объектов, т.е. объектов собственно разработанных класссов?

Comment: @Artem использовать модель